# Python data connectivity mysql need to display records from item_id<103 from table ITEMS

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Required output is [(101, 'Nik D300', 'Nik D300', 'DSLR Camera', 3), (102, 'Can 1300', 'Can 1300', 'DSLR Camera', 5)]
i tried

```
    def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SAMPLE.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("drop table if exists ITEMS")
    
    sql_statement = '''CREATE TABLE ITEMS
    (item_id integer not null, item_name varchar(300), 
    item_description text, item_category text, 
    quantity_in_stock integer)'''
    
    cursor.execute(sql_statement)

    items = [(101, 'Nik D300', 'Nik D300', 'DSLR Camera', 3),
             (102, 'Can 1300', 'Can 1300', 'DSLR Camera', 5),
             (103, 'gPhone 13S', 'gPhone 13S', 'Mobile', 10),
             (104, 'Mic canvas', 'Mic canvas', 'Tab', 5),
             (105, 'SnDisk 10T', 'SnDisk 10T', 'Hard Drive', 1)
             ]
  
    try:
        cursor.executemany("Insert into ITEMS values (?,?,?,?,?)", items)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.executemany("Insert into ITEMS values (?,?,?,?,?) where item_id <103")       
        cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS")
    except:
        return 'Unable to perform the transaction.'
    rowout=[]     
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        rowout.append(row)
    return rowout    
    conn.close()
```

i'm new to python can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1):

#use execute instead of executemany.

You can replace below lines
cursor.executemany("Insert into ITEMS values (?,?,?,?,?) where item_id <103")
cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS")

Change to

cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS where item_id <103")

Answer (score 0):

```
You can replace below lines
cursor.executemany("Insert into ITEMS values (?,?,?,?,?) where item_id <103")       
cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS")

Change to 

cursor.executemany("select * from ITEMS where item_id <103")


This should work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace below lines cursor.executemany("Insert into ITEMS values (?,?,?,?,?) where item_id <103")
cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS")

Change to

cursor.execute("select * from ITEMS where item_id <103")

***This one is working ***

Comment: Please edit your answer. Put the code inside code the bracket.